# How to create a new entity to an existing table in database?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Recently I've started to use Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2015. We have some legacy software with some existing tables.

**Question:** Is it possible to create Entities connected to those existing tables?

Comment: What do you mean by connected?

Comment: You could import your legacy data into CRM (depending on how well the attributes etc. map from system-to-system).

Comment: @Daryl by connected, I mean mapped. Consider I'm creating a `Car` object and I want it to be mapped to an already existing table `MySchema.LegacyCar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. To use this entities in CRM you will have to create this entities in CRM.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your syncing from CRM to legacy... In an CRM online environment, you'd have to rely on either custom CRM plugins communicating to a webserver that inserts into the legacy system/, or possibly Scribe, Biztalk, or even SSIS with the appropriate adapter or custom CRM SDK code.

If your CRM on prem, you have an additional option where you can sync data from the filtered views to the legacy system directly in SQL Server.

Theoretically you could write custom plugins to intercept all CRUD operations and redirect them else where, but then you would be unable to do any joins in CRM against that data.